# How do I create unicode characters with variable numbers?

Tags: python, unicode

Basically what I want to do is **print u'\u1001'**, but I do not want the **1001** hardcoded. Is there a way I can use a variable or string for this? Also, it would be nice if I could retrieve this code again, when I use the output as input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the python doc on unicode (located [Here](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)):

> One-character Unicode strings can also be created with the unichr()
>   built-in function, which takes integers and returns a Unicode string
>   of length 1 that contains the corresponding code point. The reverse
>   operation is the built-in ord() function that takes a one-character
>   Unicode string and returns the code point value:

```
unichr(40960)
```

results in the character :
u'\ua000'